# Service didn't start on Gear Sport (Tizen 3.0)

Tags: service, native, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Native wearable application launch custom service by `app_control_send_launch_request()` call, and that works fine on Tizen 2.3.2 devices (Gear S2/S3). But service don't start on  Gear Sport with Tizen 3.0: `app_control_send_launch_request()` returns `APP_CONTROL_ERROR_LAUNCH_REJECTED` error code. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try packaging service app with that wearable app from which you're trying to launch. I think it'll work.

You may go through **Remarks** section of **app_control_send_launch_request()** function in [***this link***](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?langswitch=en&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.tizen.org%2Fdev-guide%2F2.3.2%2Forg.tizen.native.wearable.apireference%2Fgroup__CAPI__APP__CONTROL__MODULE.html) to know in detail.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and accept your answer, if succeed.